# Recursively iterate trough Pydantic Model

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, pydantic

Lets say I have a model and I want to do some preprocessing on it. (for this problem it does not matter it this is pydantic model, or some kid of nested iterable, its a general question).

```
def preprocess(string):
    # Accepts some preprocessing and returnes that string

class OtherModel(BaseModel):
   other_id:int
   some_name: str


class DummyModel(BaseModel):

    location_id: int
    other_models: List[OtherModel]
    name:str
    surname:str
    one_other_model : OtherModel
```

I want to make a recursive function that will iterate trough every attribute of a Model and run some preprocessing funciton on it. For example that function can be removing some letter from a string.

I came this far and I dont know how to move further:

```
from collections.abc import Iterable
def preprocess_item(request: BaseModel) -> BaseModel:
 
    for attribute_key, attribute_value in request:
        if isinstance(attribute_value, str):
            setattr(
                request,
                attribute_key,
                _remove_html_tag(getattr(request, attribute_key)),
            )

        elif isinstance(attribute_value, BaseModel):
            preprocess_item(attribute_value)

        elif isinstance(attribute_value, Iterable):
            for item in getattr(request,attribute_key):
                preprocess_item(item)
```

This gives me the wrong answer, it basically unpacks every value. I want the same request object returned but with string fields preprocessed.

Comment: If it doesn't matter, whether or not you are dealing with Pydantic models, then you should not include that external dependency in your question (nor set that tag). However it seems that the code in your question absolutely _does_ depend on Pydantic models since you typed your function accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you *are* actually dealing with Pydantic models, I would argue this is one of the use cases for [validators](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/).

There is not really any need for recursion because you can just define the validator on your own base model, if you want it to apply to *all* models (that inherit from it):

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel as PydanticBaseModel
from pydantic import validator


def process_string(string: str) -> str:
    return string.replace("a", "")


class BaseModel(PydanticBaseModel):
    @validator("*", pre=True, each_item=True)
    def preprocess(cls, v: object) -> object:
        if isinstance(v, str):
            return process_string(v)
        return v


class OtherModel(BaseModel):
    other_id: int
    some_name: str


class DummyModel(BaseModel):
    location_id: int
    other_models: list[OtherModel]
    name: str
    surname: str
    one_other_model: OtherModel
```

If you want to be more selective and apply the same validator to specific models, they can be made [reusable](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/#reuse-validators) as well:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator


def preprocess(v: object) -> object:
    if isinstance(v, str):
        return v.replace("a", "")
    return v


class OtherModel(BaseModel):
    other_id: int
    some_name: str

    _preprocess = validator("*", pre=True, allow_reuse=True)(preprocess)


class DummyModel(BaseModel):
    location_id: int
    other_models: list[OtherModel]
    name: str
    surname: str
    one_other_model: OtherModel

    _preprocess = validator(
        "*",
        pre=True,
        each_item=True,
        allow_reuse=True,
    )(preprocess)


class NotProcessed(BaseModel):
    field: str
```

We can test both versions like this:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    dummy = DummyModel.parse_obj({
        "location_id": 1,
        "other_models": [
            {"other_id": 1, "some_name": "foo"},
            {"other_id": 2, "some_name": "spam"},
        ],
        "name": "bar",
        "surname": "baz",
        "one_other_model": {"other_id": 2, "some_name": "eggs"},
    })
    print(dummy.json(indent=4))
```

The output in both cases is the same:

```json
{
    "location_id": 1,
    "other_models": [
        {
            "other_id": 1,
            "some_name": "foo"
        },
        {
            "other_id": 2,
            "some_name": "spm"
        }
    ],
    "name": "br",
    "surname": "bz",
    "one_other_model": {
        "other_id": 2,
        "some_name": "eggs"
    }
}
```